# Import FreeCAD to Python to use in external Script

Tags: python, windows, import, scripting, freecad

I am currently working on a Projekt to get data from FreeCAD to use in an external script.

My FreeCAD installation:

`OS: Windows 10
Word size of OS: 64-bit
Word size of FreeCAD: 64-bit
Version: 0.18.4 (GitTag)
Build type: Release
Branch: releases/FreeCAD-0-18
Hash: 980bf9060e28555fecd9e3462f68ca74007b70f8
Python version: 3.6.6
Qt version: 5.6.2
Coin version: 4.0.0a
OCC version: 7.3.0
Locale: German/Germany (de_DE)`

And have problems to import this to a python script.

I am using Python 3.7.4

My Source code:

```
import sys

# Path to FreeCAD
FREECADPATH = 'C:\FreeCAD 0.18\bin'

def import_freecad(path_freecad):
    """Try to import FreeCAD on path_freecad"""
    sys.path.append(path_freecad)
    try:
        import FreeCAD
    except:
        print("Could not import FreeCAD")

import_freecad(FREECADPATH)
```

This code always raises the expection.
I followed a tutorial pdf you easily can find when google for it.

Anyone has an idea on how to solve this? Or solved the problem themself?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "anaconda way"? 
Seems easier. You can create your own virtual env.(https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands)

And then just type in terminal:

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 freecad
```